# Insert multiple rows for each row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a SQL query that inserts multiple rows of data into Table B for each row in Table A

Table A

```
ID       BillNo       TAX       Amount      TotalAmount 
-------------------------------------------------------
1        001           5        100          105
2        002           20       400          420
```

And I need the data to be inserted in table B like this format

Table B

```
ID   Type        Billno     Amount
-----------------------------------
1    Sales       001        100
2    Cash        001        105
3    Tax         001          5
4    sales       002        400
5    Cash        002        420
6    Tax         002         20
```

I tried this

```
insert into tableB 
    select 'Sales', billno, Amount 
    from TableA

insert into tableB 
    select 'Cash', billno, TotalAmount 
    from TableA

insert into tableB 
    select 'Tax', billno, tax 
    from TableA
```

But it inserts first all rows of 'sales' then 'cash' then 'Tax'. I'm not getting it in a set.
Like this:

```
1    Sales       001        100
2    sales       002        400
3    Cash        001        105
4    Cash        002        420
5    Tax         001          5
6    Tax         002         20
```

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "not in a set* ? Do you get all the rows in `Table B` that you need? A relational database table is **inherently** unsorted - there's no "natural" or "system-given" ordering - you get an order **only** if you explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` query. Therefore, what order these rows are inserted into Table_B in really doesn't matter at all ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "getting it in a set"? Would you like to insert it in a ordered way? Then you can do something like this:

chain the queries together with a union and sort it

```
insert into tableB ([Type], BillNo, AMount)
select 'sales' as [Type], BillNo, amount as AMount from TableA union
select 'cash' as [Type], BillNo, TotalAmount as AMount from TableA union
select 'tax' as [Type], BillNo, tax as AMount from TableA
order by BillNo, [Type]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you test this sql :

```
INSERT INTO `tableB` (`Type`, `Billno`, `Amount`)
SELECT 'Sales', `billno`, `Amount` 
FROM `TableA`
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you ment such query:

```
    select t.Type, billno, 
        case t.Type 
            when 'Sales' then Amount 
            when 'Cash' then TotalAmount 
            when 'Tax' then tax 
        end as Amount
    from TableA
    cross join (values ('Sales'), ('Cash'), ('Tax')) as t(Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` :

```
insert into tableB (Type, BillNo, AMount)
    select tt.type, t.billno, tt.amount
    from table t cross apply
         ( values ('sales', t.Amount),
                  ('cash', t.TotalAmount),
                  ('Tax', t.tax) 
         ) tt(type, amount)
    order by t.billno;
```